# exec / passthru error on IIS Server 6.x and Windows Server 2003

Tags: windows-server-2003, iis, php

I'm trying to run ImageMagick from batch via exec() or passthru()
I've already changed security settings for cmd.exe and ImageMagick folder. These are my current settings.

```
C:\ImageMagick-6.5.3-Q8 BUILTIN\Administrators:(OI)(CI)F 
                    COMPUTERNAME\IUSR_myusername:(OI)(CI)R 
                    NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(OI)(CI)R 
                    BUILTIN\Users:(OI)(CI)R 

C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe COMPUTERNAME\TelnetClients:R 
                        COMPUTERNAME\psaadm:R 
                        COMPUTERNAME\psacln:R 
                        COMPUTERNAME\psaserv:R 
                        NT AUTHORITY\INTERACTIVE:R 
                        NT AUTHORITY\SERVICE:R 
                        NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:F 
                        BUILTIN\Administrators:F 
                        COMPUTERNAME\IUSR_myusername:R
```

After doing this this is the actual script that I'm trying to run:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);

define("ABSOLUTE_PATH", "C:\\Inetpub\\vhosts\\myusername.com\\httpdocs\\online");
define("IMAGE_MAGICK_CONVERT", "C:\ImageMagick-6.5.3-Q8\convert.exe");
echo(IMAGE_MAGICK_CONVERT . " " . ABSOLUTE_PATH . "\\convert\\myfile1.jpg " . ABSOLUTE_PATH . "\\convert\\myfile1.pdf");
echo exec("cmd /c " . IMAGE_MAGICK_CONVERT . " " . ABSOLUTE_PATH . "\\convert\\myfile1.jpg " . ABSOLUTE_PATH . "\\convert\\myfile1.pdf 2>&1");
passthru(IMAGE_MAGICK_CONVERT . " " . ABSOLUTE_PATH . "\\convert\\myfile1.jpg " . ABSOLUTE_PATH . "\\convert\\myfile1.pdf 2>&1");
```

So I'm still receiving a Access is denied. Please help out...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed it finally.. It was due security issues as expected ...

Answer (score 0):

Run [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) and watch to see what operation exactly is failing.  It could well be writing to the ABSOLUTE_PATH\Convert directory.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't doubling your backslashes in `IMAGE_MAGICK_CONVERT`.